# Field Service Mobile App - Cannot update Global Actions

Tags: mobile, field-service-lightning, global-actions, fieldservice, fsl

> **UPDATE:**
>
> The screenshot below is from the [Field Service Mobile App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salesforce.fieldservice.app&hl=en_GB&gl=US). Not the standard [Salesforce App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salesforce.chatter&hl=en_GB&gl=US).
>
> Is the Field Service Mobile App limited in terms of editing Global Actions?
>
> When editing the publisher layout - it does not change the Global Actions menu on the app.

The screenshot below is from a user that can only see 3 Global Actions.
[image]

I have added a new Global Action: 'New Expenses' to the only publisher layout, and checked the publisher layout assignments.

[image]

I am new to field service, and have 2 queries:

1. What could be the reason for the 'New Expense' global action not showing? My guess is that FSL has custom layouts that I have not found - but I could be wrong.
2. There are several other global actions from the publisher layout not displaying - is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the **publisher layouts** from Setup. You will be able to add that component in the publisher layout to its directed layout. I mean which ever layout you might be using. generally, the layout name is Global action.

Comment: Please see the second screenshot showing my global action added to the publisher layout - unfortunately this did not solve my issue.